# Create new factor based on values of other factors in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have `DF1`:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(Before = factor(c("Bad", "Bad", "Good", "Good", "Bad", "Bad")),
                 Now = factor(c("Good", "Good", "Good", "Bad", "Bad", "Good")))
```

I want to create a new factor `Change` based on the values of factors `Before` and `Now`, so that change from `Bad` in `Before` to `Good` in `Now` is `Better` in the new factor and so on:

```
DF2 <- data.frame(Before = factor(c("Bad", "Bad", "Good", "Good", "Bad", "Bad")),
                 Now = factor(c("Good", "Good", "Good", "Bad", "Bad", "Good")),
                 Change = factor(c("Better", "Better", "No change", "Worse", "No change", "Better")))
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in base R:

```
DF1$Change <- unlist(Map(function(x,y){
  if (x==y){
    return("No change")
  } else if (x=="Bad"){
    return("Better")
  } else {
    return("Worse")
  }
}, DF1$Before, DF1$Now))
```

or using `purrr`:

```
DF1$Change <- unlist(purrr::map2( DF1$Before, DF1$Now, function(x,y){
  if (x==y){
    return("No change")
  } else if (x=="Bad"){
    return("Better")
  } else {
    return("Worse")
  }
}))
```

**Output:**

```
> DF1
  Before  Now    Change
1    Bad Good    Better
2    Bad Good    Better
3   Good Good No change
4   Good  Bad     Worse
5    Bad  Bad No change
6    Bad Good    Better
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't achieve the intended outcome.

Comment: @KaC sorry missed one thing. Let me modify

Comment: @KaC check it out

Answer (score 1):

The following function creates a new column depending on the values `"Good"` and `"Bad"`.

```
change <- function(x, y){
  n <- length(x)
  x <- as.character(x)
  y <- as.character(y)
  out <- rep("Better", n)
  out[x == y] <- "No change"
  out[x > y] <- "Worse"
  out
}

DF2 <- DF1
DF2$Change <- change(DF2$Before, DF2$Now)

DF2
#  Before  Now    Change
#1    Bad Good    Better
#2    Bad Good    Better
#3   Good Good No change
#4   Good  Bad     Worse
#5    Bad  Bad No change
#6    Bad Good    Better
```

This function can also be in a `magrittr` pipe, outputing to `DF2`.

```
library(dplyr)

DF1 %>% mutate(Change = change(Before, Now)) -> DF2
```

Comment: Inspired in this [`Map`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62581116/8245406), but simpler: `mapply(change, DF1$Before, DF1$Now)`.

Comment: @KaC Glad to help, no sadness :).